# How do I write a loop to repeat the code?

Tags: python, loops

I am a very beginner in Python and I want to repeat this code. But I don't really know how to do this without "goto". I tried to learn about loops but did not understand how to apply them.

```
import requests
addr = input()
vendor = requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text
print(addr, vendor)
```

Comment: `while True: <your code>`

Comment: This is an excellent free course for learning the basics of programming: https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-computer-science-harvardx-cs50x

Answer (score 3):

Create a function `repeat` and add your code in it. Then use `while True` to call it infinitely or `for i in range(6)` to call it 6 times:

```
import requests
def repeat():
  addr = input()
  vendor = requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text
  print(addr, vendor)
while True:
  repeat()
```

Note that goto is not recommended in any language and is not available in python. It causes a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is the best way to achieve this. For example check out this pseudo code:

```
While person is hungry
Eat food a bite of food
Increase amount of food in stomach
If amount of food ate fills stomach
person is no longer hungry
stop eating food
```

In code this would look something like this:

```
food_in_stomach = 0

while food_in_stomach <= 8:
  eat_bite_of_food()
  food_in_stomach += 1
```

You could therefore implement your code like the following:

```
times_to_repeat = 3
 
while times_to_repeat > 0:
  addr = input()
  vendor = requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text
  print(addr, vendor)
  times_to_repeat -= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a variable, and then say that as long as the variable is true to its value, to repeat the code in the for loop.