# How do I get my code to be repeated by any amount of times specified by the user?

Tags: python, repeat

I am trying to make a program that calculates a persons profit after investing in a dividend stock but I want the code to be repeated as many times as specified by the user as the user may hold the stocks for 1 year or 50 years.  This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
def repeat():
 invested = float(input('Please write exactly how much you invested, for example - 310.84'))

 div = float(input('Please enter the dividend yield of your stock yield as a percentage, for example - 3.1% (dont include the percentage sign)'))

 t = input('How long are you considering holding the stocks for in years?  Example - 6')


 deci = float(div) / 100

 equ = float(invested) * float(deci)

 y1 = float(equ) + float(invested)
while True:
  repeat()
```

As you can see I have created a function that takes the input from the user of how long they intend to hold the stock (t), but I am unsure how I get my equations to be repeated by this amount of times.

So far the code runs smoothly, no errors and I achieve the expected results.

EDIT - added a repeat function, now i'm unsure how to get the repeat to end after x amount of times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python how to repeat code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747894/python-how-to-repeat-code)

Comment: There's no function on your code and if you've achieved "_the expected results_", what's your question? Please be specific.

Comment: Have you considered reading the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)? It teaches you things like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat something, there are 2 main ways I can think of to do so:

1. for loops:

```
times_to_repeat = int(input("How many times would you like to repeat this code? ")
for i in range(times_to_repeat):
    repeat()
```

2. While Loops:

```
times_to_repeat = int(input("How many times would you like to repeat this code? ")
var1 = 0

while times_to_repeat > var1:
    repeat()
    var += 1
```