# Repeating main task

Tags: python

I am making a personal project that's a Slot Game. I need the user to input if they want to play again, but I can't figure out how to make it repeat

I tried to make a function called repeat:

```
def repeat(Money):
Win(Money)  
print(WinCheckValue, Money)
playagain(Money)
repeat(Money)
```

And defining, itself meaning it would repeat but it would only ever run play again and repeat never the other functions.

All code (i'm new to python):

```
import random


Money = 10

def SlotRoller(number1, number2):
    return random.randint(number1, number2)

slot1 = SlotRoller(1, 3)
slot2 = SlotRoller(1, 3)
slot3 = SlotRoller(1, 3)

match slot1:
    case 1:
        slot1 = "cherry"
    case 2:
        slot1 = "grape"
    case 3:
        slot1 = "orange"

match slot2:
    case 1:
        slot2 = "cherry"
    case 2:
        slot2 = "grape"
    case 3:
        slot2 = "orange"

match slot3:
    case 1:
        slot3 = "cherry"
    case 2:
        slot3 = "grape"
    case 3:
        slot3 = "orange"

WinCheckValue = [slot1, slot2, slot3]

def Win(Money):
    Money = Money - 1
    match WinCheckValue:
        case ["orange", "orange", "orange"]:
            print("!Big Win!")
            Money+=25
            return Money
        case ["grape", "grape", "grape"]:
            print("!Big Win!")
            Money+=25
            return Money
        case ["cherry", "cherry", "cherry"]:
            print("!Big Win!")
            Money+=25
            return Money
    playagain(Money)
            
def playagain(Money):
    n = input("Would you like to play again? (y/n)")
    if n == "y":
      Win(Money)
    else: print("Ok")
    
def repeat(Money):
    Win(Money)        
    print(WinCheckValue, Money)
    playagain(Money)
    repeat(Money)
repeat(Money)
```

Comment: Start with the working single-game code. Then, move everything into a function and call that function once. This should now behave as before. If not, adapt accordingly. Now, instead of calling the function once, you call it in a loop. After each run, you ask whether the user wants another game and, if they don't, you break out of the loop. BTW: Just to make it easier, start writing a separate program. Put in `print('hello world!')` as sole code and then rewrite this to use a loop as previously described.

Comment: Use a loop, not recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) (the "valid response" in your case could be they don't want to keep playing).

Comment: And [How do I write a loop to repeat the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747894)

Comment: Please fix indentation

Answer (score 0):

I did some slight refactoring, but this should meet your needs.

```
import random


def slot_roller(number1, number2):
    return random.randint(number1, number2)


def check_slot(number_input):
    match number_input:
        case 1:
            return "cherry"
        case 2:
            return "grape"
        case 3:
            return "orange"
        case _:
            return None


def check_results(slot_results):
    print(slot_results)
    match slot_results:
        case ["orange", "orange", "orange"]:
            print("!Big Win!")
            return True
        case ["grape", "grape", "grape"]:
            print("!Big Win!")
            return True
        case ["cherry", "cherry", "cherry"]:
            print("!Big Win!")
            return True
    return False


def play_again():
    n = input("Would you like to play again? (y/n)")
    if n.lower() == "y":
        return True
    else:
        return False


def gamble(gambling_money):
    gambling_money -= 1
    slot1 = slot_roller(1, 3)
    slot2 = slot_roller(1, 3)
    slot3 = slot_roller(1, 3)

    slot1_result = check_slot(slot1)
    slot2_result = check_slot(slot2)
    slot3_result = check_slot(slot3)

    result_list = [slot1_result, slot2_result, slot3_result]

    if check_results(result_list):
        gambling_money += 25
    return gambling_money


def main():
    current_money = 10
    while True:
        print('current_money', current_money)
        current_money = gamble(current_money)
        if current_money <= 0 or not play_again():
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Extra information about While loops:

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-while-loop/

Answer (score -1):

Some pseudo code for you to consider:

```
def game():
   print('Game on..')

while True:
   game()
   res = input("Do you want to continue (y/n) ?")
   if res == 'n' or res == 'N':
      break
```

Comment: You would probably need `money = game(money)` here.

Comment: @NiceZombies - I do not want to provide exact logic. That's why I mentioned its just a pseudo code. Its just a template and OP can change it according its need.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly - fixed the indentation